# linux поиск устройства в сети

Tags: linux, сеть, wifi

Работаю над системой для дома, нужно распознать, что телефон (iPhone) вошел в локальную сеть (подключился) и также нужно узнать, что он покинул локальную сеть (отключился от WiFi).

Пробовал вещи типо `arp` или `nmap`, но оне не подходят, потому что iOS может отключаться от сети для экономии батареи. Arp и nmap теряют уст-во, если оно находится "во сне". Однако, роутер всегда точно знает, что устройство подключено или отключено, значит, можно же как-то... Вопрос - как?

Comment: роутер точно также теряет устройство. А кажущаяся "видимость" - это просто dhcp lease (то есть, айпи выдается на час-другой.  И это Вы и видите)

Comment: все «потроха» семейства протоколов [ieee 802.11](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11) «зашиты» либо в железе, либо в загружаемом в устройство блобе. у каких-нибудь устройств они могут «торчать наружу», но у, вероятно, подавлющего большинства — нет. потому лучше ориентироваться на то, что лежит поверх. в вашем случае подойдёт hook у dhcp-сервера в связке с относительно мальньким lease time (порядка, например, нескольких десятков минут).

Comment: @KoVadim, да, я назначил статичную привязку dhcp нужным мне (отслеживаемым) устройствам. Осталось как-то выяснять, что эти устройства в сети. Решил каждый 15 минут отправлять пинг на них с `-r10`, а то и `-r20`, пытаясь их "раскрыть". Всё вроде бы работало, но вот незадача... минут 10 назад опять потерял устройства...

Comment: если устройство не хочет Вам отвечать, то Вы его просто так не найдете.

Answer (score 0):

Iphone имеет возможность подключаться к WiFi сети, у него есть свой mac-адрес.
Мониторить нахождение телефона можно при помощи анализа сетевых устройств airodump-ng.